# Message option popup disappears when any message is starred

Tags: feature-request, bug, chat, popups, chat-stars

Steps to reproduce:

1. Have someone star a message
2. Click the little arrow next to the message on the star list
3. Have the same person star a different message while the popup is still up

The popup disappears on starring a new message, which ruins whatever you were trying to do with it.

**Why is this a problem?** It makes it extremely hard to fight star-trolls who run in and start starring everything in sight.

**What is my request?** Keep the popup when a new message is starred instead of making it disappear.

**Alternate solution?** Make an easy one-click "unstar" button appear next to the arrow on the message, so that this won't be a problem anymore. I suspect this will cause far too much accidental star clearing though. Perhaps this could have a confirmation dialog (just like it currently does).

Comment: In the mean time, the popup is managed through client side scripting. You could user script this to bypass.

Comment: I was able to reproduce this in the c# room. Upon issuing the next star, the popout dialog closes itself if open.

Comment: More than likely this is a result of the star area being redrawn.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I know this isn't a fix, but it is at least temporary relief if you are being spammed by some star crazy user:

```
$("body").on("contextmenu","#starred-posts .img.vote",function(){
 var msgId = $(this).parents("li")[0].id.substr("summary_".length);
 var fkeyId = fkey().fkey;
 $.ajax({
  type:"POST",
  data: {fkey:fkeyId},
  url: "http://chat.stackoverflow.com/messages/" + msgId + "/unstar",
  success: function(data){}
 });
 return false;
});
```

Right click on the star image in the star summary area, split second later, star cancelled.

[image]